# Jekyll Plugin Conditional for Production vs Development

Tags: ruby, jekyll, jekyll-extensions

I'm looking for a way to either exclude a plugin during a production build of a Jekyll site or a conditional I can add inside a custom plugin so when `JEKYLL_ENV=production` the code in that plugin doesn't run.

Comment: Why not just use `bundler`? https://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/ put the gem you don't want to use in production in `group :development` Or where ever you need it e.g.  `gem "another-jekyll-plugin", group: [:development, :test]`

Comment: These aren't gems, they're custom plugins in the _plugins directory.

Comment: in that case the conditional could be wrapped around the plugin as `if ENV['JEKYLL_ENV"] == 'production'` but that seems hacky. If you were going to do this I would almost suggest pulling the plugins out to a new location and making that a conditional require statement in a file in the "_plugins" directory